# Raycasting inaccurately calculating intersections

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, 3d, raycasting

I am trying to write a raycasting algorithm described in [this](http://permadi.com/1996/05/ray-casting-tutorial-7/) article. I use a coordinate system where y increases upward, x increases to the left. The variable names in the following code snippet are taken from the article, I will describe them so that the code is easier to read:

`rayDirX` and `rayDirY` are coordinates of the vector pointing from the player's position on the map in the direction where the ray is being cast, `alpha` is the angle between this ray and the origin.

`Px, Py` are precise coordinates of the player's position on the map

`Ax, Ay` are the precise coordinates of the first horizontal intersection, later other horizontal intersections.

`Bx, By` are the precise coordinates of the first vertical intersection, later other vertical intersections.

`horXa, horYa, vertXa, vertYb` are the step increments, which are constant after finding the first intersection. I suspect that the problem with the algorithm is that these values are not calculated correctly.

`mapX, mapY` are the coordinates of the lower left corner of an intersection on a map. This is used to check if there is a wall on this position in the array `map[][]`.

Horizontal and vertical intersections are checked alternately. `Ax, Ay`, or `Bx, By` should hold the precise position of the intersection.

```
// Calculate the initial intersections
// Horizontal intersections
// If the ray is facing up
if (rayDirY > 0)
{
    horYa = 1;
    Ay = mapY+1;
}
// If the ray is facing down
else
{
    horYa = -1;
    Ay = mapY;
}
horXa = Math.abs(horYa)/tanAlpha;
Ax = Px + (Ay-Py)/tanAlpha;
// Vertical intersections
// If the ray is facing right
if (rayDirX > 0)
{
    vertXa = 1;
    Bx = mapX+1;
}
// If the ray is facing left
else
{
    vertXa = -1;
    Bx = mapX;
}
vertYa = Math.abs(vertXa)*tanAlpha;
By = Py + (Px-Bx)*tanAlpha;

//Loop to find where the ray hits a wall
//Number of texture to display
int texNum;
boolean horizontal = Math.abs(Ax * Math.cos(alpha)) < Math.abs(Bx*Math.cos(alpha));
//This loop runs for each ray with the setup above
while(true) {
    // Check horizontal intersection
    if (horizontal)
    {
        mapX = (int)Math.floor(Math.abs(Ax));
        mapY = (int)Math.floor(Math.abs(Ay));
        if(mapX > mapWidth-1) mapX = mapWidth-1;
        if(mapY > mapHeight-1) mapY = mapHeight-1;
        if(mapX < 0) mapX = 0;
        if(mapY < 0) mapY = 0;
        texNum = map[mapX][mapY];
        if(texNum > 0) break;
        Ax += horXa;
        Ay += horYa;
        horizontal = false;
    }
    else {
        mapX = (int)Math.floor(Math.abs(Bx));
        mapY = (int)Math.floor(Math.abs(By));
        if(mapX > mapWidth-1) mapX = mapWidth-1;
        if(mapY > mapHeight-1) mapY = mapHeight-1;
        if(mapX < 0) mapX = 0;
        if(mapY < 0) mapY = 0;
        texNum = map[mapX][mapY];
        if (texNum > 0) break;
        Bx += vertXa;
        By += vertYa;
        horizontal = true;
    }
}
```

Using this algorithm, the image is not rendered properly, see the screenshot. I suspect that it is because of `horYa, Ay, vertXa, Bx` not being calculated correctly. UPDATE: After some debugging efforts, it seems that sometimes we choose to compute horizontal intersection instead of vertical and vice versa... Really strange!

[image]

Can you please spot an error in the algorithm? Thank you for any input!

Comment: You could debug you implementation with known grid and ray. I've used another method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679963/precise-subpixel-line-drawing-algorithm-rasterization-algorithm/24680894#24680894

Comment: @MBo I have a known grid and ray, but I can't figure out what is wrong from the rasterized image. It's just a mess like on the screenshot above...