# How can you find the coordinates between two given points on a straight line(JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, 3d, line, rasterizing

I want to get all the x,y,z coordinates between 2 given points, on a straight line. I need to be able to do this in JavaScript for checking whether a projectile collides in my game.

So, for example:

Point 1: (0,0,0)
Point 2: (2,2,2)
-> 0,0,0 - 1,1,1, 2,2,2

Edit, here is working code for anybody who is lost.

```
def ROUND(a):

return int(a + 0.5)
```

def drawDDA(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2):

```
x,y,z = x1,y1,z1

length = (x2-x1) if (x2-x1) > (y2-y1) else (y2-y1) if (y2-y1) > (z2-z1) else (z2-z1)

dx = (x2-x1)/float(length)

dy = (y2-y1)/float(length)

dz = (z2-z1)/float(length)

print (ROUND(x),ROUND(y),ROUND(z))

for i in range(length):

    x += dx
    z += dz
    y += dy

    print(ROUND(x),ROUND(y),ROUND(z))
```

drawDDA(0,1,2,10,11,12)

Comment: There is a infinite amount of points between 2 different Points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approach will need to deal with quadrants in 2D and octants in 3D which is pain in the ass. if you use **DDA** instead (which is very similar) you will get rid of that. So:

```
P(t) = P0 + t*(P1-P0)
t=<0.0,1.0
```

This is also called **Linear Interpolation**. As there are infinite number of points `P(t)` between your two endpoints `P0,P1` I assume you want just integer ones (representing PIXELS) so you need to select `t` with single "pixel" step and round or floor the coordinates of `P(t)`. That is simple:

```
dP = abs(P1-P0)
dt = 1.0/max(dP.x,dP.y,dP.z)
```

this is called **line rasterization** and can be also ported to integer arithmetics without the need for floats. The ported version looks like this:

```
dP = abs(P1-P0)
T = max(dP.x,dP.y,dP.z)
t = {0,1,2,...,T}
P(t) = P0 + (P1-P0)*t/T
```

And even this can be improved by exchanging the `*t/T` by simple conditional increment/decrement inside loop like this:

- [Precise subpixel line drawing algorithm (rasterization algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682318/2521214)

There are also different algorithms like Bresenham for this but DDA is faster on modern architectures and also much simpler and easily expandable to any dimensionality.

Comment: I found some demo code for it, any ideas how to convert this into JavaScript?

Comment: @YangYing The code looks exactly like 3D DDA on integer math without the division I was writing about. I do not code in JavaScript but My bet is you need to change the header to match JavaScript syntax and also exchange the `setPixel(x0,y0,z0);` with function yor environment uses for pixel rendering ... I suspect something lice `Canvas->Pixels[x][y]`. Also you can not render 3D pixel on 2D screen so you need to either ignore the `z` coordinate or add some kind of projection ... unless you are rendering into volumetric data.

Comment: @YangYing take a look at [n-dimensional DDA oon integer math with subpixel start point offset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54018102/2521214) might interest you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the help, I was able to solve this using the DDA algorithm that was mentioned. I Put the python version in my question and I'll update it to JavaScript if anybody else wants it.