# Algorithm for drawing diagonals in a picture

Tags: c++, algorithm, image, geometry, diagonal

I need to draw the closest thing to a major diagonal on a picture(irregular matrix).
I already know that for a regular one the format is the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        if(i==j){
             matrix[row][column] = color_of_diagonal;
        }
    }
  }
```

But adapt that to a rectangle is obiviously different...
I saw some note algorithm but i didn't understood very well their work. Someone could help me?

P.S.: It would be cool if it could be explained a way to draw multiple "diagonal" lines on the image too, but that's not the main problem.

Comment: You should look at the [tag:bresenham] algorithm.

Comment: The code you posted fills the entire image with a color. Regardless, you're looking for bresenham's stepping algorithm.

Comment: Botje you are right i'll fix

Comment: Are you sure you want to implement graphics primitives? Do you use any graphics subsystem that might provide that?

Comment: Using two levels of loops for your square example looks like over complicated, and of course inefficient. `for (i = 0; i < row; i++) matrix[i][i] = color_of_diagonal;` would do. In addition, I suppose it is a typo to use `row` and `column` instead of `i` and `j` when  indexing the matrix.

Comment: prapin i need to operate on all the matrix so i'll use the full iteration anyway, but that's a nice advice. Thanks!

Comment: [DDA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682318/2521214) is much simpler and even faster than Bresenham these days ...anyway what you want to google is `line rasterization algorithm` which will lead you to DDA and Bresenham anyway...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, can you use a library like OpenCV? If so, then something like

```
# you need to convert this python code to c++. Should not be that difficult
r, c = matrix.shape[:2]
cv2.line(matrix,(0,0), (c-1, r-1), color= color_of_diagonal)
```

Otherwise, you need to do either do some interpolation or have something like a jaggy line.

```
# c++ code here, I am rusty a bit (we know that matrix is r rows, c cols.)
aspect = (float)c/r
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    matrix[i][(int)(aspect*i)] = color_of_diagonal
```

So, this code finds the corresponding point in the diagonal line in each row. I wrote the same code in python and here is the result

```
r, c = 100, 200
mat = np.zeros((r, c))
aspect = c/r
for i in range(10):
    mat[i, int(i*aspect)]=255
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(mat)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Another image when the image is `100*137` (kinda arbitrary)

[image: image2]

Also, notice that the complexity is pretty low, it is `O(r)` where `r` is the number of rows whereas your code will `O(r*c)`