# How to draw a line on really low resolution

Tags: geometry

I am currently working on a project on arduino which involves drawing a line on a 8x8 rgb led display, given 2 random coordinates, how do I determine which pixels between them should be painted?

Any help is apprecieated

Comment: Bresenham line algorithm.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation of the [line drawing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm) mentioned above.

Note that this example will only work if `x1` is less than `x2`.

```c
void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  int dx = x2 - x1;
  int dy = y2 - y1;

  for (int x = x1; x < x2; x++){ 
    int y = y1 + dy * (x - x1) / dx;
    plot(x, y);
  }
}

void plot(int x, int y) {
  // Draw each pixel
}
```

Comment: you can do the [same without `*,/` operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682318/2521214) (just ignore the subpixels) which make it faster than bresenham on most modern CPU architectures and easily portable to higher dimensions